# How to prevent SQL injection when doing batch insert in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, bulkinsert

I have up to 100 items I would like to insert in one batch operation. I am doing it like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (f1, f2, ..., fk) VALUES
  (v11, v12, ..., v1k),
  (v21, v22, ..., v2k),
  ...
  (vn1, vn2, ..., vnk)
```

All is fine, but I am building this string by concatenating the values as is, which means my code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

How can I continue using the bulk insert syntax on one hand, yet be protected from the SQL injection?

**EDIT 1**

I would like to provide a bit more context. The actual SQL that I am going to use (writing the code at this very moment) has the following form:

```
WITH new_parent AS (
  INSERT into parent (g1, g2, ..., gm) VALUES (v1, v2, ..., vm) RETURNING id
) INSERT INTO MyTable (parent_id, f1, f2, ..., fk) VALUES
  (new_parent.id, v11, v12, ..., v1k),
  (new_parent.id, v21, v22, ..., v2k),
  ...
  (new_parent.id, vn1, vn2, ..., vnk)
```

Comment: What's wrong with passing values through escaping function? Without it even COPY command will be vulnerable to \. sequence.

Comment: Actually, it seems that PostgreSQL can handle up to 2^15 - 1 parameters in a `PREPARE` statement, so seems like I can just replace the set of values `{vij}` with the respective named parameters of the form `$1, $2, ...` Just found out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a COPY statement - if it is possible. It is little bit faster, require significantly less memory and it is SQL injection bulletproof - because data use a different channel.

Comment: I have added **EDIT 1**. Is the COPY statement still relevant?

Comment: You need to use CTE? Why you don't use temp table with COPY?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how my query would look like if using COPY?

Comment: @mark with COPY, you need two steps - first, you create temp table, then you fill table with COPY statement. Using a COPY statement depends on your environment.

Comment: But how do I populate the temp table? Am I not back to the same problem of inserting records into a table?

Comment: @mark COPY statement can carry data from you to table - and because it is not SQL statement, then it is 100 SQL injection safe. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I do not have any data in any table initially, this is what I want to do in the first place. I do not see how I can use COPY if it assumes the data to be in some table.

Comment: To use COPY I have to have a file or STDIN as the source. I have neither.

Comment: @mark: not necessary - PostgreSQL provides API, that allow using COPY without direct access to STDIN - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq-copy.html So for Java http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html. Similar functionality exists for Perl, PHP, ..

Comment: Thanks for the information. This requires validation, which may take some time. I have to test how these functions play with transactions, after all these copy statements depend on the id of the new invoice. +1 in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a concatenated string of parameters instead of the actual values and then pass the values with a single array including all of the values in the right order. For example:

```
    CREATE TYPE paramValues AS {
    "ID" integer,
    "V1" text
    .
    .
    .
    }
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bulk(data paramValues[])
      RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE 
    
    BEGIN
        WITH new_parent AS (
          INSERT into parent (g1, g2, ..., gm) VALUES (v1, v2, ..., vm) RETURNING id
        ) INSERT INTO MyTable (parent_id, f1, f2, ..., fk) VALUES
          ($1, $2, $3, ..., $k),
          ($k+1, $k+2, $k+3, ..., $k+k),
          ...
          ($m, $m+1, $m+2, ..., $m+k);
        return 1;
    
    END$BODY$

    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```