# How to insert a single row in the parent table and then multiple rows in the child table in single SQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Please, find below my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE reps (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  rep   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE terms (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  terms TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE shipVia (
  id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ship_via  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE invoices (
  id                    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer              TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT customerNotEmpty CHECK(customer <> ''),
  term_id               INT REFERENCES terms,
  rep_id                INT NOT NULL REFERENCES reps,
  ship_via_id           INT REFERENCES shipVia,
  ...
  item_count            INT NOT NULL,
  modified              TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  created               TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  version               INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE invoiceItems (
  id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  invoice_id    INT NOT NULL REFERENCES invoices ON DELETE CASCADE,
  name          TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT nameNotEmpty CHECK(name <> ''),
  description   TEXT,
  qty           INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT validQty CHECK (qty > 0),
  price         DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);
```

I am trying to insert an invoice along with its invoice items in one SQL using writable CTE. I am currently stuck with the following SQL statement:

```
WITH new_invoice AS (
    INSERT INTO invoices (id, customer, term_id, ship_via_id, rep_id, ..., item_count)
    SELECT $1, $2, t.id, s.id, r.id, ..., $26
    FROM reps r
    JOIN terms t ON t.terms = $3
    JOIN shipVia s ON s.ship_via = $4
    WHERE r.rep = $5
    RETURNING id
) INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description) VALUES
 (new_invoice.id,$27,$28,$29,$30)
,(new_invoice.id,$31,$32,$33,$34)
,(new_invoice.id,$35,$36,$37,$38);
```

Of course, this SQL is wrong, here is what PostgreSQL 9.2 has to say about it:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_invoice"
LINE 13:  (new_invoice.id,$27,$28,$29,$30)
           ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_invoice"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 704
```

Is it possible at all?

**EDIT 1**

I am trying the following version:

```
PREPARE insert_invoice_3 AS WITH 
new_invoice AS (
    INSERT INTO invoices (id, customer, term_id, ship_via_id, rep_id, ..., item_count) 
    SELECT $1, $2, t.id, s.id, r.id, ..., $26
    FROM reps r
    JOIN terms t ON t.terms = $3
    JOIN shipVia s ON s.ship_via = $4
    WHERE r.rep = $5
    RETURNING id
),
v (name, qty, price, description) AS (
    VALUES ($27,$28,$29,$30)
          ,($31,$32,$33,$34)
          ,($35,$36,$37,$38)
) 
 INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
 SELECT new_invoice.id, v.name, v.qty, v.price, v.description
 FROM v, new_invoice;
```

And here is what I get in return:

```
ERROR:  column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 19:  SELECT new_invoice.id, v.name, v.qty, v.price, v.descriptio...
                                         ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 899
```

I guess `v (name, qty, price, description)` is not enough, the data types must be specified as well. However, `v (name, qty INT, price, description)` does not work - syntax error.

**EDIT 2**

Next, I have just tried the second version:

```
PREPARE insert_invoice_3 AS WITH 
new_invoice AS (
        INSERT INTO invoices (id, customer, term_id, ship_via_id, rep_id, ..., item_count) 
        SELECT $1, $2, t.id, s.id, r.id, ..., $26
        FROM reps r
        JOIN terms t ON t.terms = $3
        JOIN shipVia s ON s.ship_via = $4
        WHERE r.rep = $5
        RETURNING id
) 
 INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
(
 SELECT i.id, $27, $28, $29, $30 FROM new_invoice i
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.id, $31, $32, $33, $34 FROM new_invoice i
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.id, $35, $36, $37, $38 FROM new_invoice i
);
```

Here is what I get:

```
ERROR:  column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 15:  SELECT i.id, $27, $28, $29, $30 FROM new_invoice i
                            ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 759
```

Seems like the same error. It is interesting that if I remove all the `UNION ALL` and leave just one `SELECT` statement - it works!

**EDIT 3**

Why do I have to cast the parameters? Is it possible to specify the type of columns in the CTE?

Comment: The error message says it all: you are supplying a text argument for $28 (or $32 or $36), and the query expects it to be an integer. Supply the correct argument types, or cast them to integer inside the query.

Comment: It is a prepared statement - I do not pass any arguments. Also, how do I specify the type? I tried the most obvious option and it fails the syntax check. If you know how to do it - please post an answer.

Comment: `VALUES ($27,$28::integer,$29::integer,$30)` does the trick here, but yields: `ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $6` $6 appears to be unused. BTW: I do think you have _a lot of parameters_, and 27 to 38 appear to be a repeating group, too.

Comment: I am not posting the entire SQL, because the invoice creation requires 26 parameters. The parameters 27-38 correspond to three invoice items associated with the same invoice. I may have up to 100 invoice items, meaning 426 parameters in total. Do you want to say that 1 SQL statement with 426 parameters is worse than having 101 SQL statements in one transaction having the same 426 parameters in total?

Comment: How to specify types depends on the language and driver you're using. For example in C, using `PQprepare` you'd pass an array of all the argument types. Some drivers don't allow that and leave only the possibility to the server to "infer" the types.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use $N placeholders for the list of values. I've +1'ed [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476208/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-when-doing-batch-insert-in-postgresql#comment28884751_19476208) on your previous question suggesting to pass the values as literals, properly escaped. How to do it exactly depends on the client-side language/driver.

Comment: Personally, I think that having a few hundred parameters is insane. Very hard to maintain, too. It looks cleaner to have separate statements  for the orders and the order-details lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL has such an extended interpretation of the `VALUES` clause that it may be used as a subquery by itself.

So you may express your query in this form:

```
WITH new_invoice AS (
    INSERT INTO ...
    RETURNING id
),
v(a,b,c,d) AS (values
  ($27,$28,$29,$30),
  ($31,$32,$33,$34),
  ...
)
INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
 SELECT new_invoice.id, a,b,c,d FROM v, new_invoice;
```

That assumes you want to insert the cartesian product of `new_invoice` and the values, which mostly makes sense if `new_invoice` is actually a single-row value.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: For now I just cast $28 to int, the rows that follow assume the same cast by default. I wonder if I could declare the types in CTE.

Comment: The approach in @epox's answer seems cleaner (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65517141/54426). How would its effects differ from the answer given here?

Comment: @RichApodaca: the column expression `(select id from new_invoice)` would fail when there is more than 1 row in `new_invoice`. In practice it probably doesn't matter as you most probably want to insert only one invoice at a time.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH new_invoice AS (
    INSERT INTO invoices ...
    RETURNING id
)

INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
VALUES ((select id from new_invoice), $27 , $28, $29,   $30),
       ((select id from new_invoice), $31 , $32, $33,   $34),
       ((select id from new_invoice), $35 , $36, $37,   $38);
```

Comment: Does exactly what the question asks with less complexity than the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of insert ... values ...., use insert ... select ...:

```
) INSERT INTO invoiceItems (invoice_id, name, qty, price, description)
SELECT new_invoice.id,$27,$28,$29,$30 FROM new_invoice
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Cast the first line of items, or all of the lines: ($27)::text, ($28)::int, etc.

Comment: It's due to the way Postgres coerces types. With a single select, it'll infer the types based on the insert part of the statement, whereas with a union, it'll infer the type based on the first line of the union and fallback to text from lack of hints.