# PostgreSQL error: column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, casting

The query below is dynamically generated based on the number of rows that are being inserted.  For each row of data, there is an additional `UNION SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO account_sale
(qty, price, product_id)

SELECT $1, $2, t.id
  FROM inventory_product AS t
  WHERE  t.ebay_sku = $3

UNION

SELECT $4, $5, t.id
  FROM inventory_product AS t
  WHERE  t.ebay_sku = $6  
...
```

When I try to run the query, I get the following:

> error: column "qty" is of type integer but expression is of type text

The node.js page for this query:

```
module.exports = async function(orders) {
  const pool = require('./config.js');
  const client = await pool.connect();

  const sql = ...
  const data = [
    1, 1.50, 10, 
    2, 4.50, 11
  ];

  client.query(sql, data).then(res => {
  ...

  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

If I remove the `UNION` from the query, like this:

```
INSERT INTO account_sale
(qty, price, product_id)

SELECT $1, $2, t.id
  FROM inventory_product AS t
  WHERE  t.ebay_sku = $3
```

and remove the second item from `data`, there **isn't** any errors.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the parameters for the query? It seems it's an issue with the data types you're using as parameters.

Comment: @VictorP The code itself is around 100 lines.  It involves making api calls to ebay's server, then parsing the response.  The `orders` data I posted was the result of a `console.log` of the parameters right before executing the query, so it should be accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure if you copy/pasted the exact sql generated or orders array because what you posted here looks fine. Maybe you're missing a comma somewhere and it's shifting the parameters?

Comment: @VictorP I figured it out.  Working on posting an answer but I'm not sure I understand it exactly.  I have to use *typecasting* for columns after a UNION select statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix this error, you need to *cast* the types of each column in the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO account_sale
(qty, price, product_id)

SELECT $1::integer, $2::float, t.id
  FROM inventory_product AS t
  WHERE  t.ebay_sku = $3

UNION

SELECT $4::integer, $5::float, t.id
  FROM inventory_product AS t
  WHERE  t.ebay_sku = $6  
...
```

The closet thing I could find to an explanation to this is in @DenisdeBernardy 's comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516645/how-to-insert-a-single-row-in-the-parent-table-and-then-multiple-rows-in-the-chi) question:

> It's due to the way Postgres coerces types. With a single select, it'll infer the types based on the insert part of the statement, whereas with a union, it'll infer the type based on the first line of the union and fallback to text from lack of hints.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this caveat. Seems like a strange behavior, though.Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Casting the $n parameter worked for me also, in a merge statement.  My $1 param is a string, but my $2 param is an integer.  The following worked.   `merge into user as tgt using ( values ( $1, $2::integer ) ) as src ( username, age ) ...`